# Damped vibrations of a membrane stretched over a circular frame

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, orthogonality, bessel-functions

I am given this following PDE with the initial and boundary conditions with $0 < r < 1$, $t > 0$, and $v_0$ being a constant:

$u,_t,_t + 2bu,_t = u,_r,_r + \frac{1}{r} u,_r$

$u(t,r=0) = 0, \vert u(t,r=0)\vert < \infty$

$u(t=0,r)=0, u,_t(t=0,r) = v_0$

Given this information I am suppose to obtain the following solution::

$$u(t,r) = 2v_0e^{-bt}\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{J_0(z_{0n}r)}{z_{0n}J_1(z_{0n})} \frac{\sin(t\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 -b^2})}{z_{0n}^2 -b^2}$$

I am at a loss on how to start this problem. My best guess would be use to separation of variables in which case I would get the following:

$u(t,r)=h(t)*f(r)$

$\frac{h''}{h'} + \frac{2bh'}{h} = \frac{f''}{f} + \frac{f'}{rf} = -\lambda$

With the separated ODEs:

$h'' + 2bh' +h\lambda = 0$

$f'' + f' + fr\lambda$ = 0

Question: Am I going in the right direction to obtain the given solution and if not what am I missing?

Comment: You are in the right direction. The equation for $h$ will lead to a solution like $\exp(-A t) \sin(Bt)$ (because it is similar to the equation for a damped harmonic oscillator; $A$ and $B$ are some constants that you will find) and the equation for $f$ will lead to a Bessel function, because the $r$ factor in the last term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, assume that $u(r, t) = R(r)T(t)$, so the equation

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} + 2\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}
$$

transforms to

$$
\frac{1}{T}\left[\frac{{\rm d}^2T}{{\rm d}t^2} + 2b\frac{{\rm d}T}{{\rm d}t} \right] = \frac{1}{R}\left[\frac{{\rm d}^2R}{{\rm d}r^2}  + \frac{1}{r} \frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r}\right]
$$

as usual, you have two equations

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{{\rm d}^2T}{{\rm d}t^2} + 2b\frac{{\rm d}T}{{\rm d}t}  &=& \alpha T  \\
\frac{{\rm d}^2R}{{\rm d}r^2}  + \frac{1}{r} \frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}r} &=& \alpha R 
\end{eqnarray}

for some constant $\alpha$

> Time part $T$

The solution for $T$ is the one of a damped harmonic oscillator

$$
T(t) = A e^{-\mu_+ t} + B e^{-\mu_+ t} 
$$

where

$$
\mu_\pm = b \pm \sqrt{b^2 + \alpha}
$$

With the condition $u(r, t = 0) = 0 = R(r)T(0) \Rightarrow T(0) = 0$ we conclude that $A + B = 0$. Moreover, since $\alpha > 0$ leads to a purely exponential decay, we also take $\alpha < 0$ to ensure oscillations. $\color{blue}{\alpha = -\lambda^2}$
 so the solution for the time-part is

$$
T(t) = A e^{-b t}[e^{+ i t\sqrt{\lambda^2 - b^2}} - e^{- i t\sqrt{\lambda^2 - b^2}}] = A'e^{-bt}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\lambda^2 - b^2}\right) \tag{1}
$$

> Radial part $R$

For the radial part you have

$$
R(r) = C J_0 (\lambda r) + D Y_0 (\lambda r)
$$

The function $Y_0$ diverges at the origin so we require $D = 0$, the result is then

$$
R(r) = C J_0 (\lambda r) \tag{2}
$$

> Boundary conditions

With the boundary condition $u(r = 1, t) = 0 = T(t)R(1) \Rightarrow R(1) = 0$, we get $J_0(\lambda) = 0$, the solutions to this equation are the [zeros](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionZeros.html) of the Bessel function

$$
\lambda = z_{0n} ~~~ n = 0, 1, \cdots
$$

That means that our solution so far is

$$
u(r, t) = e^{-bt}\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} A_n   J_0(z_{0n} r) \sin\left(t\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 - b^2}\right)
$$

Now we can impose the final condition $\partial u(0, r)/\partial t = v_0$, which leads to

$$
\frac{\partial u(r, t = 0)}{\partial t} = v_0 = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty}  A_n\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 - b^2}J_0(z_{0n}r) \tag{3}
$$

I'm not going to show it here, but it is possible to [show](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S2040618500034067) that if $f(x) = \sum_n a_n J_\nu(z_{\nu n}x)$ then

$$
a_n = \frac{2}{J_{\nu + 1}^2(z_{\nu n})} \int_0^1 x f(x)J_{\nu}(z_{\nu n}x){\rm d}x
$$

if you apply this to Eq. $(3)$ with $\nu = 0$ you will find then

$$
\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 - b^2} A_n = \frac{2v_0 }{z_{0n}J_{1}(z_{0n})}
$$

Putting everything together you then arrive to the final solution

$$
\bbox[5px, border:2px solid blue] {
u(r, t) = 2v_0e^{-bt}\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{J_0(z_{0n} r)}{z_{0n}J_1(z_{0n})} \frac{\sin\left(t\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 - b^2}\right)}{\sqrt{z_{0n}^2 - b^2}} 
}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation

Comment: @user2569905 Happy to help